# Can't get text content to be above a masking div

Tags: css, background, jsfiddle

I have a div with a background image that should be covered with a mask effect. On that div should be some content. I'm trying to get the content to be over the mask but for some reason it isn't working. 
I added a jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/FHt9d/

Here is the code:

Html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="mask"></div>
    <div id="content"><h1>This is a header</h1></div>
</div>
```

Css

```
#container
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 246px;
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d8/Skyline_oklahoma_city.JPG')    
}

#mask
{
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(75,139,228,.8);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#content h1
{
    z-index:2;
    font-size: 32;
    color: #fff;

}
```

The text should not be covered by the mask. Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this (you missed a `position: relative;`):

```
#content h1 {
   color: #FFFFFF;
   position: relative; //missed
   z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The elements that have

```
position: absolute
```

are always on top. Same thing applies to

```
position: fixed;
```

They always float above the elements in a browser.

To minimize this, you use

```
z-index: value;
```

For the elements with position value set, you can use:

```
z-index: 1;
```

and change it for the element you want to be above others

```
z-index: 2; /* or more than 2 */
```

This will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a `position: relative;` on the `#content h1`. Indeed, `z-index` applies only on positionned elements.